# Is there a way to force a refresh of just a single header in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I want to force a refresh of just a specific section header row, not the data rows. For example, refresh the header for section 3. I know how to reload an entire section (header plus data), but can just the section header be refreshed?

EDIT: When data changes in one section of the table I want to update information in the header of a DIFFERENT section. Therefore, I need to get a reference to the section header and then refresh it.

Comment: can u check this trouble dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part?noredirect=1#comment51326939_31692692

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the header is a custom `UIView`, then you can just call `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UIView` rather than on the `UITableView`.

Comment: How do you get a reference to the section header custom UIView to call setNeedsDisplay? I know how to get a reference to a specific row, but not the header.

Comment: I believe you can do this even if the header is not a "custom" `UIView` since aren't all headers instances of `UIView`s

Comment: 1 : maintain the header views you created in an array  
OR  
2 : iterate through the UITableView subviews until you find the header with your desired view.tag

Comment: Interestingly, if you refresh a single section using [tableView reloadSections...] the other custom header views are not redrawn even if you call [customHeaderView setNeedsDisplay]. I had to reload the associated sections to get their header views to redraw.

Comment: @ChrisP & @NSInterMax: *How do you get a reference to the section header custom UIView to call setNeedsDisplay?* `UIView* sectionHeader = [self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:[indexPath section]];`

Comment: what could we do in case of custom cell in viewForHeaderInSection to reload particular viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: can u check this trouble dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part?noredirect=1#comment51326939_31692692

Comment: tableView.headerViewForSection(0)?.textLabel.text = tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: 0)

Comment: This does not seem to work if you use     self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 9):

Well, in my case, after some asynchronous task i need to update my custom section header view.

and I get it to update it's height using :
**This Swift 3+ Code**

```
//to reload your cell data
self.tableView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
// this is needed to update a specific tableview's headerview layout on main queue otherwise it's won't update perfectly cause reloaddata() is called
  self.tableView.beginUpdates()
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why reloadData() doesn't refresh section headers, and it might be a bug, but `beginUpdates() endUpdates()` also worked for me.

Comment: This helped me, was having troubles with the last section footer disappearing after reloadData

Comment: Doesn't this reload the whole table? The OP explicitly wanted only a single header reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView does *not have any such method to reload only the header view/title ...You have to reload the whole section or the table.

Comment: can u check this trouble dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part?noredirect=1#comment51326939_31692692

Answer (score -4):

I beg to differ. I've run into this while deleting rows with custom section headers and (at least in iOS 6) you can simply call:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:[indexPath section]];
```

And as long as you have proper code to return a view in that method, you can easily refresh the header for a specific section:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {

        return nil; //hide the header if there are no rows...

    } else {
        // configure or refresh the header...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if something like this is possible in UICollectionViews?

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted as such.

Comment: can u check this trouble dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part?noredirect=1#comment51326939_31692692

Comment: You are calling the table's delegate method, that's a mistake. You should either reload the table if you only have one section, or reload the individual section if you have multiple.