# For custom cell in viewForHeaderInSection reload particular viewForHeaderInSection IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to reload viewForHeaderInSection in case of custom cell in viewForHeaderInSection to reload particular viewForHeaderInSection IOS.

**I have used following code**

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

But whole section will reload

**I have try the following too By creating custom view**

*SearchHeaderView is custom view*

```
  - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

            lblPrice_Header.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cartSum] ;
            return SearchHeaderView;

        }

 -(void)cartSum :(id)sender{
   .....
   .......
    =======================================
     cartSum =cartSum+[[subArray objectAtIndex:j]  intValue]*price;

        UIView *headerVw = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:section];
        [headerVw setNeedsDisplay];
        [headerVw setNeedsLayout];

    }
```

But It wont reload the section.

I have got my section header as below

[image]

I have checked the following links

[Reloading tableView header in ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041214/reloading-tableview-header-in-ios7)

[Changing UITableView's section header/footer title without reloading the whole table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346944/changing-uitableviews-section-header-footer-title-without-reloading-the-whole-t)

Comment: r u changed the height for secton

Comment: nopes height is constant

Comment: try this link it will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501952/refresh-only-the-custom-header-views-in-a-uitableview

Comment: try this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802648/reload-section-without-reloading-section-header

Comment: it doesnt work buddy

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
UIView *headerVw = [YOURTABLEVIEW headerViewForSection:section];
[headerVw setNeedsDisplay];
[headerVw setNeedsLayout];
```

**Note:**

- To deal with specific view you can define tags As well

Hope it will work for you.